# Как осуществить поиск в бд из нескольких полей ввода в шаблоне

Tags: python, django

### Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    BLOOD_TYPES_CHOICES = [('В активном поиске', 'В активном поиске'),('Встречаюсь', 'Встречаюсь'),('Женат', 'Женат'),('Замужем', 'Замужем'),('Всё сложно', 'Всё сложно'),]
GENDER_TYPES_CHOICES = [('Мужской', 'Мужской'),('Женский', 'Женский')]
    firstname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField('Blood Type', max_length=40,blank=True,choices=GENDER_TYPES_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    osebe = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    blood_type = models.CharField('Blood Type', max_length=40,blank=True,choices=BLOOD_TYPES_CHOICES)
```

### Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from board.models import Profile



def mprofil(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        profil = Profile.objects.all() 
        return render(request, 'board/main.html', {'profil':profil})
```

### Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('mprofil', views.mprofil , name='mprofil'),
]
```

### main.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <span class="input-group-text">Имя и фамилия</span>
            <input type="text" aria-label="Имя" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" aria-label="Фамилия" class="form-control">
        </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">пол</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
          <option selected>Выберите...</option>
          <option value="1">Мужской</option>
          <option value="2">Женский</option>
          <option value="3">Оба</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Возраст</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Пример размера поля ввода" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
    </div>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample" style="margin-top: 3%;">
        <div class="accordion-item">
        {% for user in profil %}                
            <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>{{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}</strong>
                <br><h6>осебе {{ user.osebe }}</h6><code>пол: {{ user.gender }}</code>
                <br>{{ user.blood_type }} лет
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}       
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- Я не могу осуществить поиск из нескольких полей ввода , допустим если я ввёл возраст 20 лет и имя Галя и вывести всех людей кому 20 лет с именем Галя , или же я мог ввести просто пол мужской и вывести всех с мужским полом

Comment: Где осуществляется взаимодействие с БД?

Comment: дак я и хочу узнать как это сделать Как осуществить поиск в бд из нескольких полей ввода в шаблоне ты может вопрос не видел

Comment: Тогда вопрос не в том, как осуществить поиск, а как подключить базу данных.